# How to update a sub-tensor inside a tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm working with MNIST and I have a tensor of gradients with size [?,28,28,1] and I want to zero out a few of the [28,28,1] sub-tensors inside it, how should I accomplish this?

I know the indices (as a list) where I need to zero out the sub-tensors. I tried doing something like this (given below) but, [scatter.update](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_update) can only change variables not tensors. I also tried stacking up the required sub-tensors of zeroes and ones but couldn't build up the required result.

`dy_dx, = tf.gradients(loss, x_adv)
 zeroes = tf.zeros(dy_dx[0].get_shape(), tf.float32)
 dy_dx = tf.scatter_update(dy_dx, indices, zeroes)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest creating a TensorFlow constant with zeros at the locations you want to zero out and ones everywhere else.  Then you could create an op that uses `tf.multiply` to do elementwise multiplication of the constant and `dy_dx`.  Depending on the structure of your graph, you might need to feed the result to `dy_dx` in your next call to `session.run`; you can replace any Tensor with feed data, including variables and constants.

Incidentally, if you just want to apply dropout to the input layer you can use [tf.layers.dropout](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dropout)

Comment: Yes! by creating a mask right? But, can you please write or describe the code for building the mask from the array of indices in tf.

Comment: You can just create the mask as a Python list and pass it to `tf.constant` as a parameter.

Comment: And what about the case, when we cannot create it as a python list, because we have the mask already in tf?